# Extract Specific Value from string using regex extractor in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I need to be able to extract from an access token formatted like:`"access_token\":\"71da3526-3592-49fb-9810-3103aed257fe\"`.
I need to be able to get just `71da3526-3592-49fb-9810-3103aed257fe` when using `regEx` Extractor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each occurrence of `\` symbol in order to get your regex to work, it would be something like:

```
"access_token\\":\\"(.+?)\\"
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor Demo]

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions - Meta Characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl5 Regular Expression Syntax](https://mythryl.org/my-Perl5_Regular_Expression_Syntax.html)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri, that regular expression really helped a lot and solved my problem.